# Move player in all directions with touch?, Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was creating a basic scenario in Unity. Thi scene have 1 cube in the center of the room, and 1 camera(player).

I need to move the player around the cube like if was flying ( with movements at the top, bottom, left, right, inside and outside), very similar to when we move freely with the mouse on the development screen.

I need make this movement with the touch.

How can i to do?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve almost all movements you want using a standard fps mobile controller: 1 joystick and a slide area for rotation. Your forward movement will be your player's forward direction(with W in unity you move always forward) and of course transform's left/right for strafe.

The tricky part is move up/down part(even in Unity editor you have to use 2 extra keys, Q&E) but you can always move up/down just looking in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

if u use the unity standard asset 'cross platform input' (which is available in the standard asset pack for free,) then anything you program with a mouse event or click, will automatically call the corresponding touch event if use on a phone.